# How to rewrite then redirect the old URL to the rewrited URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For eg. I have this link: http://example.com/url.html. Using this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.html [L,NC]
```

Now, I am able to access the file using only http://example.com/url. But how can I redirect people accessing /url.html to /url? I have tried adding after

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1 [R=301]
```

But it gave me an infinite loop error on my browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/url.html)$ http://example.com/url
```

It takes anything matching "/url.html" and sends them to "http://example.com/url"

I just tested this out on one of my sites.

Comment: I tried to place it before and after the rewriterule and both didn't work. Either it gave me an 500 error or a infinite loop error...

Comment: Did you try replacing the rewrite rule?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. It should definitely work now.